# How can the United Arab Emirates (UAE) consist of absolute monarchies if the UAE itself has a constitution?

Tags: constitution, monarchy, united-arab-emirates

It would seem that the constitution of the United Arab Emirates (UAE) would limit the power of its monarchs to some degree, thus they wouldn't be absolute monarchs.

To what extent is the constitution a limitation on the monarchy's powers?

Comment: if "federalism" is the answer, should it be added as a tag to the question?

Comment: Joseph Stalin's Soviet Union had a constitution, too. And a pretty nice one.